# How to append text to a text file in WinAPI?

Tags: winapi, append, handle

Ive got an annoying problem, I cant append any text to the text file. Every time I open it for writing, I overwrite the data. I tried to move the file pointer to the end of the file, but no result (no writing to the file at all). 
Here is the code:

```
INVOKE CreateFile, offset filePath, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0
mov hFile, eax
mov edx, 10
INVOKE SetFilePointer, hFile, 0, 0, FILE_END
INVOKE WriteFile, hFile, offset buffer, edx, ADDR SizeReadWrite, NULL
INVOKE CloseHandle, hFile
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: See <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363778(VS.85).aspx">the MSDN example</a>. You might also want the reference of the <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx">CreateFile</a> function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the value of `edx` before the call to `SetFilePointer` and using it after the call. However, Windows API functions use the `stdcall` calling convention which is not guaranteed to preserve the `edx` register, so the value in it is destroyed, and the call to WriteFile fails.